# VBA coding: How to copy a specific column from header down till a certain number of rows (change for each excel file) to new sheet in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I really need help in VBA coding as I totally have no background in excel VBA. I did read up some basic coding but I think for the task I wanted to perform, it is far complicated for me. Basically, I wanted to copy many different columns with the headers from the original sheet to the new sheet whereby I can't copy the entire column because at a certain row below there exists some text information that I don't need. Also, the number of rows that contains data information I needed change for different excel file but I would like the code to be working for all files. Is this possible?

I attached a sample of what the data file will look like along
[image: I attached a sample of what the data file will look like along]

So I wanted columns with the shipment, vehicles, and delivery

PS. Actual file consists of many row and column and many unwanted data

```vb
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range, Rng As Range
    Dim col As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim colName As String

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1")

    With ws
        Set aCell = .Range("A1:AZ30").Find(What:="Shipment", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    '~~> If Found
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then

    '~~> Copy the entire column >> **how to change this??? I don't want the part e.g. id number to come with values under shipment**
    aCell.EntireColumn.Copy
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far? Posting your code and telling us where you got stuck helps us help you. Welcome to SO!

Comment: A good starting point would be to use the record macro functionality in Excel and then manually do a sample of what you want the program to do (I would suggest using an autofilter on the columns and excluding values you don't want and then do the copy). Then, after stopping recording, have a look at the macro that was generated which should give you a starting point to adapt the code to what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim strFound As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    'Assign to strSearch what we are looking for
    strSearch = "Test"

    'Refer to the sheet where data are
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'You could used ".UsedRange" to cover all used range of Sheet1
        Set strFound = .UsedRange.Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        'If we have results
        If Not strFound Is Nothing Then
            'Find the LastRow of the column where the finding is
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, strFound.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range(.Cells(strFound.Row + 1, strFound.Column), .Cells(LastRow, strFound.Column)).Copy
        Else
            MsgBox "No match"
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help, I tried the codes but the word "shipment" wasn't covered and it covered "Id number" that I would like to exclude

Comment: Read the comments of the code. The code as it is looks for the word "Test".

Comment: Okay, I managed to cover the area I wanted now. Thank you very much. I will try to perform coding for copying, pasting to new sheet, and looping the process next ! :)

Comment: Glad to hear that i help. if the answer help you, vote it to help to others with the same questions.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to do some loops to make this work.  So here is how I would do this for shipment and you can repeat the if statements for your other columns:

```
z = 12 'ending row
n = 12 'ending column K
y = 1 'starting column
Do While y <= n
x = 1 'starting row
    Do While x <= z
    If Cells(x, y) = "Shipment" Then
    'Grab that cell's data, perhaps by saying Sheets("OtherSheet").Range("A1") = cells(x,y) or wherever you are looking to put this data.  Insert perhaps another Do loop here to iterate x down until the data reaches an end or until z so that you can grab all the data under "Shipment".
    Else
    End If
    x = x + 1 'go to the next row
    Loop 'ends after z is reached
y = y + 1
Loop 'ends after column K is reached
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Data for the suggestion :)